# Import plugin class joomla 2.5

Tags: plugins, joomla, import, joomla2.5

How do I import a plugins class so I could use the variables on my page?

For example in another plugin there would be something like

```
class plgSystemSomeplugin extends JPlugin
{
$pluginvariable='something';
}
```

Is there a way I can use something like:

```
import class'plgSystemSomeplugin'
echo $pluginvariable
```

On my page?

I can't seem to find any documentation on this at all.

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you more want a module than a plugin for Joomla. If you are writing a custom component, you can handle plugins like so: http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_plugins_in_your_component

Answer (score 3):

You can use following code.

```
$plugin = JPluginHelper::getPlugin($type, $name);
echo $plugin->varName;
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question the code has to be

```
JLoader::import('joomla.plugin.plugin');
```

How to use a plugin can be found in this documentation http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin. But I agree with David that you probably want to create a module or component. Plugins in Joomla are not the same as plugins for Wordpress.